# VBScript WinHTTPRequest Error "This method cannot be called until the Open method has been called"

Tags: vbscript, winhttprequest

I have the following code in VBScript:

```
On Error Resume Next 


Dim WinHttpReq, strFile, strMsg
dim Status, StatusText 

Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")  

WinHttpReq.open "GET", myURL, false   

WinHttpReq.SetCredentials GXP_USER_LOGIN,GXP_USER_PASSWORD,0
WinHttpReq.SetTimeouts 0,60000,60000,60000    
                          
WinHttpReq.Send 
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error at Send() method :  " & Err.Description
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

When I run the script, the msgbox displays the following error: "This method cannot be called until the Open method has been called""

I don't know why this error appears. I am already calling the Open() method before the Send() method...

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line because if the `WinHttrpReq.open` line is erroring it will be skipped that's how `On Error Resume Next` works. The code continues in an error state but you don't check for an error so `WinHttpReq.Send` tries to run but `WinHttpReq.Open` has been skipped causing the error you see.

Comment: @user692942 If Open() method would have failed, I would expect to see that in MsgBox as well right?

Comment: No, please look through the answer in the duplicate target. The way `On Error Resume Next` works is if a line errors for some reason the `Err` object is populated with the error details and the line itself is **skipped** (so it never runs). If you don't catch `Err` using an `If Err.Number <> 0 Then` statement and another error happens the same thing will happen, the `Err` object will be populated with the new error details and the line will be **skipped**. So here you are only capturing the second error completely skewing your understanding of the issue.

Comment: @user692942 Got it. I will try